# Power BI - How to run multiple identical or similar calculations without creating separate measures for each one?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am creating a report in Power BI. Most of the data comes from a table in a DB2 database. The table looks a bit like this, though I can use SQL to query and transform the table if necessary:

| Customer_ID | Year | KPI_1 | KPI_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023 | 100 | 10% |
| B | 2023 | 150 | 12% |
| A | 2022 | 75 | 15% |
| C | 2022 | 100 | 8% |

This is a simplified version; in reality there are several more KPIs. I also have a second table with a yearly forecast for each KPI; the two tables are joined in a 1 to many relationship.

On the report, I want to show the following figures for each KPI, with the years being dictated by a slicer:

- This year's total
- Last year's total
- Growth vs last year's total
- 3 year average
- Growth vs 3 year average
- This year's forecast
- Growth vs this year's forecast

I can do this with DAX by creating a measure for each figure. With the 2 KPIs in my example this would require 14 measures, which is fine. However, because there are many more KPIs in the actual data, the number of measures required would increase significantly (I estimate at least 200).

Having so many measures seems inefficient since the logic behind a lot of them will be identical, e.g.

```
KPI_1_growth_vs_last_year = ([KPI_1_this_year] - [KPI_1_last_year])/[KPI_1_last_year]
KPI_2_growth_vs_last_year = ([KPI_2_this_year] - [KPI_2_last_year])/[KPI_2_last_year]
```

It feels like there should be a way to save this logic once and then apply it to different KPIs, rather than recreating it multiple times.

Other measures will be very similar, e.g.

```
KPI_1_this_year = calculate(sum(mytable[KPI_1]), mytable[Year] = selectedvalue(mytable[Year]))
KPI_1_last_year = calculate(sum(mytable[KPI_1]), mytable[Year] = selectedvalue(mytable[Year])-1)
```

Again, it seems inefficient to have separate measures saved.

Also, even with display folders and naming conventions, 200+ measures will be a pain to navigate.

Does anyone know if there is a way to show the required figures without needing to set up hundreds of identical and/or very similar measures please?

Comment: You may be able to use Calculation Groups https://www.sqlbi.com/calculation-groups/

Comment: Agree with @jon - calculation groups are the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer provided by @Jon in the comments:

> You may be able to use Calculation Groups sqlbi.com/calculation-groups